# Custom view with lot's of canvas.drawCircle calls. Sluggish UI

Tags: android

I have a custom view which does a lot of `draw calls` in its `onDraw method`:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("start drawing");
    for(Wall w : wallManager.walls) {
        drawWall(w, canvas);
    }
    for(int[] particle : particleManager.getParticles())    {
        drawParticle(particle[0],particle[1], canvas);
    }


    int x = (int) (Math.sin(angle) * 1000);
    int y = (int) (Math.cos(angle) * 1000);
    canvas.drawLine(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth()/2+x, getHeight()/2+y, anglePaint);
    System.out.println("stop drawing");
}
```

`drawParticle` is called at least 5000 times.

Now when I press a random button the `GUI` feels really sluggish and the onclick handler is called with a large delay. I also get the following warning:

```
Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My first thought was that the onDraw method of the custom view was too slow, but then I found out that the onDraw method is never called during the whole process of clicking the button.

My **layout.xml** file is really simple and looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="nothing"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/step_count"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="nog geen stappen"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/start_queueingButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start queueing"/>

<smartps.tudelft.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

But the strange thing is: `when I remove the drawParticle calls from the onDraw method, the issue disappears`.

Is Android redrawing my custom view when I touch a button without calling onDraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing all views except the MapView in one separate container fixed the problem. I think the ripple effect (which applies to the background of the parent view of the button) causes the MapView to redraw without calling onDraw.